# Bluetooth file sharing without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a way to send files via bluetooth without pairing in android?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a part of doc which I found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices). RFCOMM channels is used here for bluetooth communications. This might help you in understanding that pairing is necessary.

> paired means that two devices are aware of each other's existence,
>   have a shared link-key that can be used for authentication, and are
>   capable of establishing an encrypted connection with each other. To be
>   connected means that the devices currently share an RFCOMM channel and
>   are able to transmit data with each other. The current Android
>   Bluetooth API's require devices to be paired before an RFCOMM
>   connection can be established.

Again below,

> If the two devices have not been previously paired, then the Android
>   framework will automatically show a pairing request notification or
>   dialog to the user during the connection procedure. So when attempting to connect devices, your application does not need to be concerned about whether or not the devices are paired. Your
>   RFCOMM connection attempt will block until the user has successfully
>   paired, or will fail if the user rejects pairing, or if pairing fails
>   or times out.